# Jquery validation not working in Bootstrap Flatui modal dialog box

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, modal-dialog

I have two forms a: login , b: forgot password
Login form is normal while forgot password is modal

1. I can validate the normal login form
2. If I put forgot password form like a normal form(without making it modal) it still validates
3. When I make the form modal it just goes to submit without going to validation.

**How to use jquery validation for Flatui Modal Dialog boxes?**

Login.jade

```
.form-signin
  form(name='loginForm', id='loginForm', action='/users/session', method='post')
    #loginError
    p.error.label.label-danger= message
    h4.form-signin-heading Please sign in
    input.form-control(type='email', name='email', placeholder='Email address', autofocus)
    input.form-control(type='password', name='password', placeholder='Password')
    button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block(type='submit') Log in

  a#forgotpassword(data-toggle='modal', data-target='#forgotPasswordModal') Forgot Password?

  // Modal
  #forgotPasswordModal.modal.fade.in(tabindex='-1', role='dialog', aria-labelledby='modalForgotPassword', aria-hidden='true')
    .modal-dialog
      .modal-content
        .modal-header
          button.close(name='forgotPasswordForm', id='forgotPasswordForm', type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-hidden='true') ×
          | You will shortly recieve a mail with instructions for resetting your password.
        .modal-body

          form.form-signin(name='forgotPasswordForm', id='forgotPasswordForm', action='/forgotpassword',method='post')
            p
              label(for='password') Email:
              input.form-control(type='email', style="width:250px" name='email', id='email', placeholder='Email address', autofocus)
              #forgotPasswordError

            p
              button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary(type='submit', id='forgotPasswordSubmit', data-dismiss='modal') Submit
```

And my custom js file is

```
   // Login Form validation
$("#loginForm").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        password: {
            required: true
        },
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
        }
    },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.addClass('label label-danger block');
        error.appendTo('#loginError');
    },

    // Look for highlight and unhighlight options to include bootstrap popovers

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
// forgot password form validation
$("#forgotPasswordForm").validate({
    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        email: "Please enter a valid email address."
    },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.addClass('label label-danger block');
        error.appendTo('#forgotPasswordError');
    },

    // Look for highlight and unhighlight options to include bootstrap popovers

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please show the ***RENDERED*** HTML markup as seen in the browser.

Comment: You do not need a `submitHandler` if all it contains is `form.submit()`... that is the default.  Just remove `submitHandler` entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You have not shown any of the rendered code that toggles your modal.

However, the following should help you come to the solution.

The `.validate()` method is how the plugin is *initialized* on the form.  Normally, `.validate()` is called within DOM ready, which is the same point when a static form's HTML has been constructed and is already in the DOM.

In your case, I presume that since your form is within a modal, it does not yet exist in the DOM.  The solution is to follow this logical order....

1. Trigger opening of Modal and creation of HTML for form
2. Call `.validate()` to initialize plugin on form within Modal

Comment: Hi Sparky, I didn't show the codes toggling my modal because I am using FlatUI framework( built on top of bootstrap with some extra features). So i am creating dialog box with FlatUI classes and data-targets. Doing it pure jquery way (ex: http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/ZrfhU/), it works. So, I am assuming it has to be issue with flatui. I have opened an issue in their github. For now, I will just make the dialog box without FlatUI.